# What is Single View Application and how is different from single page application?

Tags: android, xamarin, single-page-application, multi-page-application, application-types

I want to know what is single View Application.
what are its properties and is it different from single page application.
and if yes how?

Comment: Single View Application means the application will has a MainActicity in default .We can also call it single page application .

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what is single View Application. what are its
> properties

If you create a `single View Application`, you can see the description in the screenshot:

[image]

An Android app with a `single Activity` and simple layout file. Use this basic template as a starting point for any Android app.

> is it different from single page application.

I think it's same as single page application because it created a default Activity as a starting point of your app. If you don't like the default Activity, you can choose to create a `Blank App` and create your own activity.